# How do I compare a utf-16 buffer to a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-16

I have a buffer that looks like this:

```
<Buffer 50 00 6f 00 77 00 65 00 72 00 50 00 6f 00 69 00 6e 00 74 00 20 00 44 00 6f 00 63 00 75 00 6d 00 65 00 6e 00 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ...>
```

When this buffer is read with  `utf-16le` or printed with .toString() this is "PowerPoint Document"

However, if I do:

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('test.ppt',{start:1152,end:1215,encoding:'utf16le'})
    stream
    .on('data',function(chunk){
        console.log(chunk.toString().trim());
        console.log(chunk.toString().trim().length);
        if(chunk.toString().trim() === "PowerPoint Document"){
            console.log('yay');
        }else{
            console.log('boo');
        }
```

This prints:

```
PowerPoint Document  
32
boo
```

How can I compare these?

Comment: You just answered your question. You use `.toString()` to convert it to a string, *then* compare it.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I've tried that. See my edits

Comment: Check their `.length`s

Comment: @zerkms the length of the `chunk` is 32, and doing `trim()` on it doesn't change that

Comment: Do you mean:  How to make it log "yay"?  You are already comparing the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string ends with nulls.  Since bytes 1152-1215 look like

```
0480h: 50 00 6F 00 77 00 65 00 72 00 50 00 6F 00 69 00  P.o.w.e.r.P.o.i. 
0490h: 6E 00 74 00 20 00 44 00 6F 00 63 00 75 00 6D 00  n.t. .D.o.c.u.m. 
04A0h: 65 00 6E 00 74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e.n.t........... 
04B0h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

All those null bytes at the end will get converted into `\u0000`, so you're actually comparing:

```
'PowerPoint Document\u0000\u0000...' === 'PowerPoint Document'
```

...which is obviously false.

End at byte 1189.

BTW: stream `data` events are not guaranteed to fire with all of the data you requested.  It may fire multiple times with only parts of the data (that's why it's called `chunk`).  You have to buffer up all of the `data` events until you get an `end` event, then do your comparison.

Comment: I added `trim()` to the string (see my edits in the question` and it still doesn't evaluate to true

Comment: @zerkms yes, and it still says the length of `chunk` after trimming is still `32`

Comment: @Houseman have you checked what characters go right after the `PowerPoint Document`? (hint: `.charCodeAt()`)

Comment: Actually, the space conversion was old node behavior.  It now just puts unicode nulls (`\u0000`), which `trim()` doesn't strip.  End your stream at the correct byte.

Comment: @josh3736 that is crazy if it actually converted `0x00` into a space :-S

Comment: @josh3736 doing a subString to trim out the extra characters worked

Comment: @Houseman: Why use substring instead of just requesting only the bytes you actually need in `createReadStream`?